# Xcode Cloud access private repo with Access Token

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud, ci-scripts

My issue is that I have one of the dependencies is on the private repo.
I use SPM and the repo is protected with login/token.
To get the code locally I have a `.netrc` file with my credentials.
This part works.
When I setup a Xcode Cloud pipeline, it fails because it tries to get the codebase from that repo and fails. The easiest part would be to get someone from that repo to authorise an give an access Xcode Cloud (which I requested already).
But the problem is that the company which use the system is not super keen (aka too much bureaucratic)  to share access to any other services.
So it ruins the pipeline.

I'm wondering if there's a way I could tell Xcode Cloud to use my credentials inside `ci_post_clone.sh` script file ?

When I tried to just copy/paste the content from .netrc with same format:

```
machine xxxx.xxxx.com
login MY_LOGIN
password  MY_TOKEN
```

the script fails.

Any thoughts how to make it work?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?